# Node JS server proxy using additional paths not working

Tags: node.js, odata

I have a simple node js server like this:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverOne = 'http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/';

    app.use(express.static('webapp'));
    app.use(express.static('./'));

app.all("/attendance/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1: ' + serverOne);
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

So address `localhost:3000/attendance` should redirect me to `http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/` but it is not, I am getting 404.

I was able to make it work when I set the proxy path as `"/*"` instead of "/attendance/*", but when I wanted to access entity set "AttendanceSet" via `localhost:3000/AttendanceSet` it also gave me 404. Do I need to create proxy for all my paths? Shouldn't the `/*` do that?

When I check initialisation of oDataModel in SAPUI5 app I can see such a request (In this case I have set "/*" for the proxy):

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/$metadata?sap-language=EN
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from disk cache)
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

By this logic, I should be able to access entity set `AttendanceSet`, but I guess I am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For urls like `localhost:3000/AttendanceSet` or `localhost:3000/Attendance` you have to remove the `/` you have in you endpoint like this.

```
app.all("/attendance*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1: ' + serverOne);
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
```

Comment: Removing "/" did not help. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem was with cache. I deleted browser cache and also, when running node js server I used addition -c-1 to do no caching.